When making a Music Bot with Distube, the sound does not come out when the music ends
I am writing a music bot, but when the song is finished with distube, the sound does not come out.
index.js
const { getVoiceConnection } = require('@discordjs/voice');

distube.on('finish', async queue => {

const connection = getVoiceConnection(queue.guild.id);


if (connection) {
  connection.destroy(); // Bu ses kanalından çıkacaktır
  console.log('Ses kanalı kapatıldı.');
} else {
  console.log('Ses bağlantısı bulunamadı.');
}
});

How do I solve this problem? It says there is no guild ID.
Please find a solution, I wrote the bot with distube
